# Lists containing number

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a loop that checks whether a certain number in lists in a list is not appearing. For example: if I have the list

```
[[1,'O', 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 'X']]
```

I want to write a loop that checks whether number `2` appears in one of the lists, and if not, asks you to pick a new number. So far I'm stuck on this:

```
move = 2
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if move not in board[i][j]:
            move = int(input("Number already taken. Pick another"))
```

But it doesn't work. It seems to be a fairly straightforward check, but I don't know why it wouldn't run. Does anybody have a better suggestion how to check these lists for a given number?

Cheers

Comment: How doesn't it work? What is `board`? We can infer, but it would help if you provided a [mre]. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: if you want to operate with 'move in collection', use collection instead of int/str. board[i][j] is not a collection, otherwise change if not move == board[ i ] [ j ]

Answer (score 6):

try to use `any` function.

```
m = [[1,'O', 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 'X']]
while True:
    move = int(input('....'))
    if any(move in row for row in m):
        break
```

Comment: You can replace `found = any([move in row for row in m])` with `found = any(move in row for row in m)`

Comment: It works! Thanks! however, the problem I now face: this is not a loop, because after the first try you can still put in a wrong number. I try " while not found'  but then I enter an infinite loop. How do I put this in a right loop?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression):

```
my_list = [[1,'O', 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 'X']]

move = 2
numbers = (e for l in my_list for e in l)

if move not in numbers:
    move = int(input("Number already taken. Pick another"))
```

a more compact version:

```
numbers = (e for l in my_list for e in l)
move = 2 if 2 in numbers else int(input("Number already taken. Pick another"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your environment:

```
target = 2
list_of_lists = [[1,'O', 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 'X']]
```

I would do something like that with a one-liner:

```
True in [target in element for element in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

While Andrea's answer is more concise and clean, the answer to why your code does not work is because you are comparing two variables with the `not in` comparator which expect a list on the right hand. More info on that here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

So to solve it, either remove the inner loop and compare the `move` with the inner lists, or use an `equality` comparator instead. Both options are below:

```
board = [[1,'O', 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 'X']]

move = 2
for i in range(3):
  if move not in board[i]:
    move = int(input("1: Number already taken. Pick another"))

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if move == board[i][j]:
            move = int(input("2: Number already taken. Pick another"))
```